# JavaScript speechSynthesis is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the speechSynthesis and this is my code:

```js
const speechBtn = document.querySelector('#speech-btn');

const speak = () => {
  const msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello world');
  msg.rate = 0.7;
  msg.pitch = 1;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
  console.log('test');
};

speechBtn.addEventListener('click', speak);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="speech-btn">Read</button>
    <script src="./text-to-speech.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it's not working.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and indicate where your JavaScript is within the HTML so that we can replicate your issue and provide an answer.

Comment: Works fine here

Comment: Same. Works perfect. Browser & version?

Comment: Thanks guys. But if I run it in Chrome, I can't hear anything.

Comment: I ran it in Chrome and it worked. Check your console for errors? Make sure your computer's volume is up and not muted?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome (windows)

Comment: I had to enable Siri on my Mac to be able to hear the voice, which is very strange. What if I don't want to use Siri but just want to be able to use text-to-speech feature? It doesn't make sense to me.